# How do you change the cmake generator in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cmake

For some reason it forces -G Ninja when I try to build within eclipse.  I would prefer Eclipse just not specify the -G option to cmake, but I can't figure out how to configure Eclipse to do that.

For exampe, this in my console window:

```
Building in: /home/bgass/eclipse-workspace/scomlib/build/default
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON /home/bgass/eclipse-workspace/scomlib
CMake Error: Error: generator : Ninja
Does not match the generator used previously: Unix Makefiles
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file or choose a different binary directory.
cmake --build . -- -v
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Build complete (0 errors, 0 warnings): /home/bgass/eclipse-workspace/scomlib/build/default
```

In a terminal it works just fine without the generator specified.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON /home/bgass/eclipse-workspace/scomlib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/bgass/eclipse-workspace/scomlib/build/default
```

Comment: The built-in CMake support in eclipse-cdt is quite new and didn't get a lot of attention recently. Currently, there is no way to specify the generator. I recommend the plugin [cmake4eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cmake4eclipse). It works very well and is actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I always execute `cmake` outside eclipse and open the generated eclipse project in Eclipse.

use `-G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"` to specify Eclipse as the generator.

Following are the full set of Eclipse generators.

```
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
```

Type in `cmake --help` to see what generators are supported by your specific cmake version.

Comment: the question is related to build-in eclipse cmake projects.